# Signal Processing noise detection

Tags: java, matlab, signals

Is there any alogrithm in Digital Signal Processing for detect noise in ECG signal with adaptive threshold, I made alogrithm but when it have a diseases detect as a noise
Anyone give a general solution for this issue???

I did noise detection depend on wavelet transform

Answer (score 0):

There can be different types of noise, for example - signal overflow, when almost all values have maximum or minimum levels.
A high level of 50-60Hz in the signal spectrum can be induced by the electrical network. There may be a floating baseline, when the difference in average values per second is comparable to the amplitude of the peaks (wavelet transform can help here).
Frequencies above 60 Hz are most likely noise (if you have 200-300 samples per second). High frequencies share of 20-50 Hz is most likely noise.
Normal QRS complex provides two strong maximums of ~8-12Hz and 1-2Hz in the signal spectrum, the absence of such maximums may indicate pure noise (but may be also VF case).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).